# How to analyze this hash of hash example?

Tags: perl

For the following code snippet, is my understanding of `$label = $classifier->{result}->{forcast}->[$i]->{label};` correct?

1)  result is used as the key for hash ref of classifier;

2)  forcast is used as the key for hash ref of $classifier->{result}

3)  $classifier->{result}->{forcast} is a ref to an array, and i-th value of this array is also a hash reference

4)  The label is the key of the hash reference $classifier->{result}->{forcast}->[$i]. The corresponding value is assigned to the left side of $label.

```
my $i=0;
while (<classifierinput>)
{
   $label = $classifier->{result}->{forcast}->[$i]->{label};
   $i++;
}
```

Comment: How is classifierinput defined?  What is this code supposed to accomplish?

Comment: Your understanding is correct. I'll just add that between two consecutive sets of indexing brackets (either array or hash), the dereferencing arrow is optional. So your example can be written `$classifier->{result}{forcast}[$i]{label}` (the first dereferencing arrow is not optional as it isn't between two sets of brackets).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your understanding is correct.